# tt_news template_latest delete the <p> tags

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tt-news

I am using Typo3 and tt_news in my page, I have two views to display news, one is a ###TEMPLATE_LATEST### and one is ###TEMPLATE_SINGLE###. I edited my tt_news_v3_template so it displays as I want

Both have the same code in the template, but the ###NEWS_CONTENT### is having diferent behaviours, in the single display, the content is displayed good, with all his `<p>` tags generated in the editor, but the latest new view is having a problem, it deletes all the `<p>` tags, so my text is not being correctly formated

Somabody have an idea about how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below typoscript:

```
plugin.tt_news.general_stdWrap.parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE
```

Answer (score 0):

add following lines in template script of root

In Constants :

`content.RTE_compliant = 0`

In Setup :

`tt_content.stdWrap.dataWrap >`
`lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines>`